# Evince 'save as' permissions

Tags: permissions, pdf

If I `Save As` a `.pdf` file opened in `Evince` PDF viewer, it will always save it with `600` permissions regardless of what permissions the original file had. Is it possible to configure it in such a way that it saves files with broader permissions, like `644`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by changing the file write mode of the user by using `umask` command.
for your case use

```
umask 0133
```

Note:By making this change not only files created by `Evince` PDF viewer will have that permisssion, instead all files created by that particular user will have 633 permissions.

Comment: Don't rely on "all files" having that permission setting. Shell, and most standard commands, will honour that setting. But some executables will ignore it -- for example, databases will usually set up schema, table and index files so you can only alter them through the product itself. IIRC, files will never be given execute permissions by default either, so 0133 is the same as 0022.

Comment: Yeah you are correct Paul, but i felt for that question giving too many details isn't necessary.

Comment: Sorry, but I marked as "solved" prematurely. Evince still saves files with 600 permissions. I changed the `umask` value to 0002 (I actually want that, not 0133) in `.bashrc`, and also inserted `export UMASK=0002` into it. Even after starting a new session, Evince still saves with 600. Other apps don't seem to have this problem, for example Mousepad saves with 666 (I'm using Xfce).

Comment: Sorry, I meant `664` not `666`.